# Power BI Default Option for Slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have a radio button slicer, is there a way I can make the first option the default option selected upon opening the file?

Comment: It will be loaded they way it is saved. If you select an option during the designing of the report and save it, it will be selected when you open it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711179, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822625, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63480482